# Did Senators Sanders and Warren support Section 232 tariffs on steel and aluminum?

Tags: united-states, politics, trade, bernie-sanders

A [PIIE article](https://www.piie.com/blogs/trade-investment-policy-watch/where-do-democratic-presidential-candidates-stand-trade) states

> **Senators Bernie Sanders and Elizabeth Warren** strongly oppose free trade pacts such as TPP and USMCA, **support Section 232 tariffs on steel and aluminum**, and are intensely critical of China. Apart from USMCA, their positions do not differ greatly from President Trump.

I'm a bit skeptical, because Warren's [long policy statement](https://medium.com/@teamwarren/trade-on-our-terms-ad861879feca) on trade doesn't mention section 232 tariffs.

So what (if anything) did Sanders and Warren say explicitly in support of section 232 tariffs on steel and aluminium?

Answer (score 5):

I managed to find [one of Sander's position statements](https://www.sanders.senate.gov/newsroom/press-releases/sanders-statement-on-trump-tariffs) on this (but not Warren's so I'll accept an answer on that):

> Donald Trump’s haphazard and reckless plan to impose tariffs on Canada and the European Union is an absolute disaster that will cause unnecessary economic pain to farmers, manufacturers and consumers in Vermont and throughout the country.
>
> I strongly support imposing stiff penalties on countries like China, Russia, South Korea and Vietnam to prevent them from illegally dumping steel and aluminum into the U.S. and throughout the world. American steel and aluminum workers need our help, and they need it now, but not at the expense of farmers, workers, small businesses and consumers in Vermont and throughout this country. Given Vermont’s proximity to Canada and our strong trade relations with Canada, these policies will be especially harmful to Vermont and other northern border states. It simply makes no sense to start a trade war with Canada, the European Union and others who are engaged in fair trade, are not cheating and where workers are paid a living wage with good benefits.

So Sanders seems to have supported the measure on some countries but not on others.

Comment: Bernie adamantly advocated in 2016 for tariffs for the purpose of bringing back manufacturing jobs. https://www.politico.com/story/2016/04/donald-trump-bernie-sanders-trade-221506 https://www.politifact.com/north-carolina/statements/2016/jul/27/donald-trump/donald-trump-says-he-and-bernie-sanders-are-very-s/